# Using Selenium to remove PopUp

Tags: python, popup, alert

I am using Selenium to remove a PopUp from investing.com but i am not able to recognise the PopUp correctly. The code I am using is ;

I need to click the button "Got it"...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\…….\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://uk.investing.com/indices/mining-historical-data/")

browser.switchTo().frame(browser.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://prefmgr-    cookie.truste-svc.net/cookie_js/cookie_iframe.html?parent=https://consent-pref.trustarc.com/??    layout=gdpr&amp;type=investingiab2&amp;site=investing-iab.com&amp;action=notice&amp;country=gb&amp;locale=en&amp;behavior=expressed&amp;uid=dc7cd041-d8c4-4102-9522-1025da9b6e09&amp;privacypolicylink=https://uk.investing.com/about-us/privacy-policy&amp;iab=true&amp;irm=undefined&amp;from=https://consent.trustarc.com/')]"")));
sleep(3)
browser.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Got it']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The popup is inside an iframe and elements ids change so it is a bit challenging.

Sometimes a second popup appears, make sure run this code before it.

This code is for closing the first popup.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\…….\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://uk.investing.com/indices/mining-historical-data/")
sleep (3)

# get iframe element
title = "TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager"
frameElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@title="TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager"]""")

# get id iframe
id = frameElement.get_property("id")
print(id)

# switch to iframe element
browser.switch_to.frame(id)

sleep (1)

# get element to click
elemet = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@class='call']""")
print(elemet.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

# click element
elemet.click()

# switch the control back to the parent frame
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I receive the following error when running the …#get iframe element
 File "<ipython-input-119-d3bded43fe69>", line 3
    frameElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@title="TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager"]
                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Comment: ..my mistake..i didn't add …..""")…..to the end.

Comment: Great @Merc! You can consider mark the question as answered ;)